# Configure software to show specific filetype in file->open dialog

Tags: windows-7, file-types

I use TexnicCenter as an editor for `.tex` files and `.lua` files as well.  In the `file->open` dialog box, only certain filetypes are shown by default (e.g. `.tex`, `.sty`, `.bib` etc.).  In order to open a `.lua` file, I need to select `All Files` from the pulldown menu which is a hassle.  Having the menu default to `All Files` is not a great solution because I then have to sort through the many garbage files that reside in the directory.  I have associated `.lua` files with TexnicCenter, but this does not add them to the menu.

[image]

Is there a way to add custom filetypes to the list of default files so that I don't need to keep doing this?  "Use a different editor" is a valid suggestion, but for now I would like to see if this is possible using my current editor.

Comment: The suggestions here might help you: [How do I view only specific extension types in Outlook's "attach file" explorer window?](http://superuser.com/questions/584626/how-do-i-view-only-specific-extension-types-in-outlooks-attach-file-explorer)

Comment: While this is usually compiled into the application, I think there are tools that allow you to manipulate GUI elements on-the-fly.  However, some of these tools rely on code injection, which may require administrator/root privileges.  Alternatively, you could modify the compiled binary itself in hopes of fixing the file filter (they are just stored as plain-text strings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is controlled by the application. In code the application seeds the drop-down list and specifies the default. You would need to submit a feature request to the product developer to change this behavior.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I sort of figured so, but thought there may have been something in the registry that could make it happen.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely not.  The pull downs are generally hard coded in the software and unless it provides a method for it add those file types I do not believe it is possible.